# Dynamic TSQL - Chaining Large Queries Together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This may be a silly question, but I'm new to dynamic sql and its limitations (do's and dont's, which I'm reading the blessings and curses of Dynamic SQL).

However I'm trying to convert a template like script into dynamic sql. I got through it pretty well until I got stumped on this particular issue.

This one particular part of my script is over 500 lines long, 1/4 of it or so are columns and renaming those columns for some; the other portion of that length are many other left outer joins of subqueries.

I know I could set the variable to nvarchar(max), but is it better to try and fit so much text or is it better to divide it up among large size variables and concat them together and attempt to exec the enter concat'd query?

Thankfully the result of this large query goes into a table that can be referenced outside the dynamic session (if I'm saying that correctly). Any thoughts?

For memory reuse is it best practice to set that variable to null once its completed its work?

Thanks for any thoughts and apologies on the length of the question.

Comment: Well if you are so interested in conserving memory, don't use NVARCHAR unless you need to. Plus VARCHAR can hold 8000 characters(double that of NVARCHAR). In reality, each variables max size is only 8KB which is very small nowadays so I don't think you should worry about memory usage of storing the script.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for this information. I was initially using nvarchar to get the output from an earlier much smaller query which is being used input to another. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sp_executesql and you can pass in a sql string of up to 2GB if its declared as a nvarchar(max):

(from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

*If a Unicode constant is specified, it must be prefixed with an N. For example, the Unicode constant N'sp_who' is valid, but the character constant 'sp_who' is not. The size of the string is limited only by available database server memory. On 64-bit servers, the size of the string is limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of nvarchar(max).*

Comment: thanks. That is working now, the other issue I ran into now was the output window size and length limitation. Its just to much text to output.